# How can I get "Simple Scan" to see my Brother MFC-7362N network scanner?

Tags: hardware, printer

I have a Brother MFC-7362N multi-function printer/scanner/copier on my local network. The Brother printer/scanner definitely works as I can print and scan from Windows and macOS on other machines.

I am running Elementary OS 5.0 Juno on a Lenovo Thinkpad T430s.

I followed the Linux install instructions from the Brother site [here](https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1b.html?c=au&lang=en&prod=mfc7362n_as&redirect=on). My device is listed as a `brscan4` device. The final step in the list to confirm the installation indicates that installed correctly. I can ping the Brother printer/scanner from the command line.

However, "Simple Scan" says no device can be found. As does `scanimage` when run from the command line.

I am very new to elementary OS, and to Linux, so I am not even sure what the next step is to try and diagnose the problem.

Where should I be looking next to try and find out which part is missing/not configured correctly?

Comment: Hi CMZ, welcome to eOS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. I have added a tag your post  so that other easily find your question when they are searching for the same topic.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a brother printer so I can't check it on my computer.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can print but cannot scan. Unfortunately I already used this method provided by your answer to install my drivers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install all of the necessary components - doh!

The Linux instructions on the Brother web site were not clear enough for me.

The missing step was [here](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=au&lang=en&prod=mfc7362n_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625). Following the steps there got printing and scanning working correctly.